# CDDIS GNSS download via urllib

Tags: python, gps, download, url

I want to update a [GNSSpy](https://github.com/GNSSpy-Project/gnsspy) function that downloads precise orbits (sp3 files) from the [CDDIS](https://cddis.nasa.gov/Data_and_Derived_Products/CDDIS_Archive_Access.html) data repository *---which now requires authentication and error handling*. I want to work with what [GNSSpy](https://github.com/GNSSpy-Project/gnsspy) already has.

With the help of [pyTMD](https://github.com/tsutterley/pyTMD/blob/main/pyTMD/utilities.py) utilities which will build an urllib opener and check CDDIS (earthdata) credentials.

```py
import os
import sys
import ssl
import base64
import posixpath
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    from urllib import quote_plus
    from cookielib import CookieJar
    import urllib2
else:
    from urllib.parse import quote_plus
    from http.cookiejar import CookieJar
    import urllib.request as url
#-- PURPOSE: "login" to NASA Earthdata with supplied credentials
def build_opener(username, password, context=ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS),
    password_manager=True, get_ca_certs=True, redirect=True,
    authorization_header=False, urs='https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov'):
    """
    build urllib opener for NASA Earthdata with supplied credentials
    Parameters
    ----------
    username: str or NoneType, default None
        NASA Earthdata username
    password: str or NoneType, default None
        NASA Earthdata password
    context: obj, default ssl.SSLContext()
        SSL context for url opener object
    password_manager: bool, default True
        Create password manager context using default realm
    get_ca_certs: bool, default True
        Get list of loaded “certification authority” certificates
    redirect: bool, default True
        Create redirect handler object
    authorization_header: bool, default False
        Add base64 encoded authorization header to opener
    urs: str, default 'https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov'
        Earthdata login URS 3 host
    """
    #-- https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html#id5
    handler = []
    #-- create a password manager
    if password_manager:
        password_mgr = url.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
        #-- Add the username and password for NASA Earthdata Login system
        password_mgr.add_password(None, urs, username, password)
        handler.append(url.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr))
    #-- Create cookie jar for storing cookies. This is used to store and return
    #-- the session cookie given to use by the data server (otherwise will just
    #-- keep sending us back to Earthdata Login to authenticate).
    cookie_jar = CookieJar()
    handler.append(url.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar))
    #-- SSL context handler
    if get_ca_certs:
        context.get_ca_certs()
    handler.append(url.HTTPSHandler(context=context))
    #-- redirect handler
    if redirect:
        handler.append(url.HTTPRedirectHandler())
    #-- create "opener" (OpenerDirector instance)
    opener = url.build_opener(*handler)
    #-- Encode username/password for request authorization headers
    #-- add Authorization header to opener
    if authorization_header:
        b64 = base64.b64encode('{0}:{1}'.format(username, password).encode())
        opener.addheaders = [("Authorization","Basic {0}".format(b64.decode()))]
    #-- Now all calls to urllib2.urlopen use our opener.
    url.install_opener(opener)
    #-- All calls to urllib2.urlopen will now use handler
    #-- Make sure not to include the protocol in with the URL, or
    #-- HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm will be confused.
    return opener

#-- PURPOSE: check that entered NASA Earthdata credentials are valid
def check_credentials():
    """
    Check that entered NASA Earthdata credentials are valid
    """
    try:
        remote_path = posixpath.join('https://cddis.nasa.gov','archive')
        request = url.Request(url=remote_path)
        response = url.urlopen(request, timeout=20)
    except url.HTTPError:
        raise RuntimeError('Check your NASA Earthdata credentials')
    except url.URLError:
        raise RuntimeError('Check internet connection')
    else:
        return True
```

Then we can change the [GNSSpy](https://github.com/GNSSpy-Project/gnsspy) function so:

```py
def get_sp3(sp3file, directory=os.getcwd()):
    """
    This function downloads IGS orbit file from NASA CDDIS ftp server.
    """
    fileName = sp3file + ".Z"
    if os.path.exists(fileName) == True:
        if os.path.exists(fileName[:-2]) == True:
            print(fileName[-2] + " exists in working directory")
            return
        else:
            print(fileName + " exists in working directory | Extracting...")
            Archive(fileName + ".Z").extractall(os.getcwd())
            return
    internet = check_internet()
    if internet == False:
        raise Warning('No internet connection! | Cannot download orbit file')
        
    username = 'someusername'
    password = 'somepassword'
    
    build_opener(username, password)
    #-- check credentials
    check_credentials()
    
    server  = 'https://cddis.nasa.gov/archive/'
    sp3FileDir = 'gnss/products'
    if sp3file.startswith("wum"): 
        sp3FileDir += '/mgex'
    file_topath = os.path.join(directory, fileName)
    fileDir = [server, sp3FileDir, fileName[3:-7], fileName]
    site= '/'.join(fileDir) # FTP link of file

    try:
        print('Downloading:', fileName, end = '')
        
        request = url.Request(site)
        #url.urlretrieve(ftp, file_topath)
        
        # Create an http response object
        with url.urlopen(request) as response:
        # Create a file object
            with open(file_topath, "wb") as f:
            # Copy the binary content of the response to the file
                shutil.copyfileobj(response, f)
        
        print(' | Download completed for', fileName)
        Archive(fileName).extractall(os.getcwd())
    except:
        print(" | Requested file", fileName, "cannot be not found!")
```

When I follow the instructions and execute:

```py
import gnsspy as gp
stn = gp.read_obsFile('./log_rinex/Ctwn-SB_obs_log_202111081430.obs')
```

`./log_rinex/Ctwn-SB_obs_log_202111081430.obs exist in working directory | Reading... Observation file  ./log_rinex/Ctwn-SB_obs_log_202111081430.obs  is read in 6.46 seconds.` 
and:

```py
orbit = gp.sp3_interp(stn.epoch, interval=stn.interval, sp3_product="igs", clock_product="igs")
```

I get:

```py
Downloading: igs21830.sp3.Z | Download completed for igs21830.sp3.Z
 | Requested file igs21830.sp3.Z cannot be found!
patool: Extracting igs21830.sp3.Z ...
patool: running C:\Users\miniconda3\envs\rt_ppp-env\Library\bin\7z.EXE e -oC:\rtklib_realTime_PPP\log_rinex -- igs21830.sp3.Z
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Input In [104] in <cell line: 1>
    orbit = gp.sp3_interp(stn.epoch, interval=stn.interval, sp3_product="igs", clock_product="igs")

  File ~\miniconda3\envs\rt_ppp-env\lib\site-packages\gnsspy\position\interpolation.py:23 in sp3_interp
    yes   = readFile.read_sp3File(yesterday)

  File ~\miniconda3\envs\rt_ppp-env\lib\site-packages\gnsspy\io\readFile.py:569 in read_sp3File
    isexist(sp3file)

  File ~\miniconda3\envs\rt_ppp-env\lib\site-packages\gnsspy\funcs\checkif.py:86 in isexist
    extract_archive(fileName + ".Z", outdir=_CWD)

  File ~\miniconda3\envs\rt_ppp-env\lib\site-packages\patoolib\__init__.py:684 in extract_archive
    return _extract_archive(archive, verbosity=verbosity, interactive=interactive, outdir=outdir, program=program)

  File ~\miniconda3\envs\rt_ppp-env\lib\site-packages\patoolib\__init__.py:484 in _extract_archive
    run_archive_cmdlist(cmdlist, verbosity=verbosity)

  File ~\miniconda3\envs\rt_ppp-env\lib\site-packages\patoolib\__init__.py:421 in run_archive_cmdlist
    return util.run_checked(cmdlist, verbosity=verbosity, **runkwargs)

  File ~\miniconda3\envs\rt_ppp-env\lib\site-packages\patoolib\util.py:227 in run_checked
    raise PatoolError(msg)

PatoolError: Command `['C:\\Users\\miniconda3\\envs\\rt_ppp-env\\Library\\bin\\7z.EXE', 'e', '-oC:\\rtklib_realTime_PPP\\log_rinex', '--', 'igs21830.sp3.Z']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

The `.sp3.7` has a file size of 13KB. It should be 96KB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went with [CDDIS](https://cddis.nasa.gov/Data_and_Derived_Products/CDDIS_Archive_Access.html) instruction.

`.netrc` in the `HOME` folder (Users/username) then:

```py
# Makes request of URL, stores response in variable r
r = requests.get(address, timeout=20)
# Opens a local file of same name as remote file for writing to
with open(file_topath, 'wb') as fd:
     for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1000):
          fd.write(chunk)
# Closes local file
fd.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful for you, I have shared 3 links for the GPS data, the first one which is CDDIS ask for user credentials but the latter two doesnot. So, you can plug the link of any one of the two sites in your code. Please do and let us know.

CDDIS:
https://cddis.nasa.gov/archive/gnss/products/

IGN:
ftp://igs.ensg.ign.fr/pub/igs/products/

SIO:
ftp://garner.ucsd.edu/pub/products/